# Best Practice to Get Roles of Active Users = Auth::user()

Tags: laravel, roles

I have 3 table

1. users
2. roles
3. role_users

this table created by Orchid Platform, i want to get role name of Auth::user() in Dashboard Laravel 8 (/home) from role_users table, i have tried to add role_id to users table, thats realy work.

But i want use role_users, because Orchid Platform use role_users.
Please help me, thank you.

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship; a User can have many Roles, and a Role can have many Users. Look up the documentation for how to handle that: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about "Orchid Platform" but that User<->Role ([ManyToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)) relationship is a pretty common database structure.

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string
 
roles
    id - integer
    name - string
 
role_user
    user_id - integer
    role_id - integer
```

**User Model:**

```php
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

**Role Model:**

```
class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

To get roles of the authenticated User

```php
$user = User::find(1);
 
foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    //
}
```

If your users will only have 1 role, you can just use a method in your `User` model to get first role of the User.

```php
public function getRole(){
  return $this->roles()->first();
}
```

Now, you can used this way:

```php
Auth::user()->getRole()->name
```

Comment: `getRole()` is better as an Accessor: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators, like `public function getRoleAttribute() { return $this->roles->first(); }`, then `Auth::user()->role->name`, but otherwise, this is great 

Comment: @TimLewis Yes that works too. But I personally prefer to use accessors to transform, or generate new attributes. But with relationships it may generate confusion because `Auth::user()->role->name` it may seen as a 1-1 "relationship" but if you use `Auth::user()->role()` and try to use Query Builder methods, you will have an error.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a valid point too; I was more going with that the syntax for `Auth::user()->getRole()->name` seems odd when compared to just `Auth::user()->role->name`, but good callout on an attribute vs a relationship; I didn't think of that. Not a use case I've run into before, but maybe defining both a `role()` and `roles()` relationship could make more sense, or a `primaryRole()`, etc. Still a good answer though 

Comment: For now i'm using getRole, thankyou guys it's work 

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm a new user and the button is secondary class